# Python Shapely seems to assign wrong point to polygon

Tags: python, gis, shapely

I'm doing some mapping of coordinates to a geojson file using shapely, but it seems that the mapping is wrong. In the image below (from geojson.io) you see the polygon and in yellow the point I want to map. In this case shapely tell me that the point is inside the polygon, but as you see this is false.

[image]

My code:

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

upzs = open('upzs.geojson', encoding='utf-8')
upzs = json.load(upzs)

point = Point(-74.09008026123047,4.719461869021348) # longitude, latitude

for feature in upzs['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if point.within(polygon) == True:
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
```

My output:

```
EL RINCON
EL RINCON
```

('EL RINCON' is the name of the wrong polygon)

You can donwload the geojson file from this [link](https://datosabiertos.bogota.gov.co/dataset/30105648-f24f-41b3-8e88-50004c3bf972/resource/d1af0f51-2e29-4371-ae60-86e13dc6b2b9/download/pensionadosactivosupz.geojson) if you want to test it

Comment: your code return this on me, ```Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
  File "C:\Lab Stackoverflow\readDir.py", line 31, in <module>
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])```

Comment: @Rizquuula, thanks for your feedbak. I've updated the link to the correct geojson file

Comment: I'm not sure I am following... you talk about a point and a polygon, but the image seems to show two polygons (one grey, and one smaller, outlined in yellow).

Comment: @TurePålsson, The one in yellow is a point,  I just drew a square for visibility. If you check the code sample I assign it  as a  coordinate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your posted image is really EL RINCON in the GeoJson file?

I got a very different shape when I run the below on jupyter notebook.

```py
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

upzs = open('pensionadosactivosupz.geojson', encoding='utf-8')
upzs = json.load(upzs)

point = Point(-74.09008026123047,4.719461869021348) # longitude, latitude

for feature in upzs['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if point.within(polygon) == True:
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
        display(polygon)
```

[image]

Also, the point is included in the polygon if I map it (using other packages, all available on pip).  Find the white circle towards the bottom.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
p = Point(-74.09008026123047,4.719461869021348)

x = gpd.read_file("pensionadosactivosupz.geojson")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x[x.NOMBRE=="EL RINCON"].plot(ax=ax)
ax.scatter([-74.09008026123047], [4.719461869021348], c="white")
mplleaflet.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Right, just looking at the lat/long values in the polygon, it's clear that the point is inside.

Comment: @Kota Mori you're right. You can notice how the polygon I posted is inside the polygon you posted. The confusion I had is the two polygons have the same name: "EL RINCON", The big one is something that in my city is called UPZ ( Planning Zone Unity) that encompasses neighborhoods, and sometimes the UPZ and the neighborhood have the same name. Also the neighborhod file is another one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, maybe you show a wrong polygon ?

This is my code

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
import folium

upzs = open('upzs.geojson', encoding='utf-8')
upzs = json.load(upzs)

point = Point(-74.09008026123047,4.719461869021348) # longitude, latitude

for feature in upzs['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if point.within(polygon) == True:
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print(feature['properties']['NOMBRE'])
        break

m=folium.Map(location=(5,5),zoom_start=6)
folium.Marker([4.719461869021348,-74.09008026123047], popup=folium.Popup('hello',max_width=1000),
              tooltip='click here').add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: you're right. You can notice how the polygon I posted is inside the polygon you posted. The confusion I had is the two polygons have the same name: "EL RINCON", The big one is something that in my city is called UPZ ( Planning Zone Unity) that encompasses neighborhoods, and sometimes the UPZ and the neighborhood have the same name. Also, the neighborhood file is another one. Thanks for your help!